# Prevent import_ipynb from executing imported file

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I have two `.ipynb` and I am using import `import_ipynb` to import a function from file `B.ipynb` in file `A.ipynb`, but when I use `from A import something` this runs file `A.ipynb` and print what I printed in that file:
File `A.ipynb`:

```
for i in range(0, 5):
    print(i)
    
def something():
    return 'something'
```

File `B.ipynb`:

```
import import_ipynb
from A import something

print(something())
```

When I run `B.ipynb` the output is:

```
importing Jupyter notebook from A.ipynb
0
1
2
3
4
something
```

But I just imported the `something` function and I do not want the print function to be executed in file `A.ipynb`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `__main__ == "__name__"` to file A which prevents it from running if it's imported.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    for i in range(0, 5):
       print(i)
    
def something():
    return 'something'
```